# Flutter project ,asset folder not choosing 2X and 3X folder automatically according to device size.Is is always choosing 1x on every screen size

Tags: flutter, image, dart, assets

Flutter project, asset folder not choosing 2X and 3X folder automatically according to device size. Is is always choosing 1x on every screen size.

I want flutter to choose image from a specific folder according to device size. But It is not working currently.

[image: asset added in project directory]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcaDF.png)

**pubspec.yaml**

assets:

- assets/locales/
- assets/images/
- assets/images/2X/
- assets/images/3X/

```
Container(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
                // color: Colors.red,
  child:
  Image.asset(
    'assets/images/home_screen_image.png',
                  // Images.homeScreenImage,
  ),
),
```

I want this code block should choose image from 1x for small device screen size and from 2x for big screens and from  3x for extreme big screens.

Currently I am using 6.0" screen size and it is choosing 1x image.

Answer (score 0):

Your asset folder name should be as `2.0x` and `3.0x`

```
- assets
   - 2.0x
      - home_screen_image.png
   - 3.0x
      - home_screen_image.png
   - home_screen_image.png
```

In `pubspec.yaml`, just mention the root folder. No need to mention specified folder `n.0x`.

```
assets:
  - assets/locales/
  - assets/images/
```

Comment: tried but not still not working

Comment: Can you remove `specified folder` from `pubspec.yaml`, and try